# Catch Exceptions I cannot handle anyway

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core

I developed an API for CRUD operations.
It's .NET Core and I have a global exception handler who catches all exceptions, I do not handle in my code. 
The exception with stack trace is logged and the API returns a general error message with Status 500.

Now lets say somebody wants to add a new product to the database. For this my API is called.
Now the product (for some reason) has no valid name. My business logic checks the name of the product and throws a "NameNotValid" exception with a message: "The product you tried to insert has no valid name."

Now I could do two things:

- Catch the NameNotValid exception in my controller and return the e.message to the user and do the logging.
- Do nothing and let my global exception handler catch the exception

The first approach is more work and the only advantage I see, is that the user will get a message what was wrong with his request.

If I do not catch the exception at all, the global handler will write to the log and the user will get only "Something went wrong".

Is there any best practice how to handle such cases?
My general question would be:

*"If I throw an exception but I cannot "handle" it nicely and save the operation in one of the
upper layers, should I ever catch it? Or should I always use the
global exception handler?"*

Comment: If I was consuming your API and tried to submit an invalid name, it would be very helpful if you told me that. A generic "something went wrong" message is pretty useless. How would I know that the name is invalid? I'd have to contact you for support, you'd have to check the log, and get back to me. All that time could be saved with a friendly message in the API.

Comment: Exceptions are not for general validation, so don't rely on your 'global' handler to do such. I don't really see a benefit there. You're just masking the issue by putting the responsibility in an inappropriate place in your code for the sake of convenience(?)

Comment: 500 is an internal Server Error => I'd call the ( _your_ ) Support Hotline. But an invalid Field is not really an "internal Server Error" is it? I'd say it is more of a "400 - Bad Request" which can be enriched by detail error information. 500 would be my last resort, only.